# DNA's physical properties

Tags: organic-chemistry, dna-rna

If we took a bunch of DNA molecules and put them together what properties would it have?

I learned that long molecules tend to make a solid substance because they get tangled. A single DNA molecule is very very long so I guess it has to be solid as a substance. I also guess it would be resistant to pulling it apart. Is it true? Has anyone actually tried doing that?

Comment: Yes, I've cyrstallized DNA from peas before. We used PCR on the isolated DNA to bring the concentration up to a practical amount to work with then used a procedure involving absolute ethanol and a hook to retrieve the DNA as fibrous , geletinous strands (which looked like a little white clump ), although small you could easily observe the pure DNA.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding first of two questions:
Assuming duplex DNA (dsDNA), the molecules should repel each other and thus stay in solution at low ionic strength, such as in Tris/EDTA buffer. This is due to the abundance of negative - repulsive - charges. Increasing the ionic strength of the solution, such as high concentration of sodium acetate should neutralize the charges and allow the dsDNA fibers to sediment. In fact, a controlled sedimentation condition may help crystallize the nucleic acids.